# Optimal control problem with a path constraint which involves controls at two distinct time points

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control

I am faced with an optimal control problem in continuous time which includes a path constraint
which involves controls at two distinct points in time.

I do not know how to approach this problem. I do not even know what
to search for, since I am not sure about the correct terminology regarding
the constraint. I would be happy about any type of input regarding
how to approach this problem, as well as for references or terminology.
Here is more detail:

Let $\mathbf{x}(t)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the state and $\mathbf{u}(t)\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$
the control, $t_{0}$ the initial time and $t_{f}$ the final time.
The goal is to minimize
$$
\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{f}}f\left(\mathbf{x}(t)\right)dt
$$
subject to laws of motion
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)=g(\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t))
$$
an integral constraint
$$
\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{f}}h\left(\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t)\right)dt=0
$$
path constraints
$$
k(\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t))=0\ \forall t\in[t_{0},t_{f}],
$$
and a path constraint of the type
$$
u_{1}(t)-u_{2}(\tau\cdot t)=0\ \forall t\in\left\{ t:t_{0}\leq\tau\cdot t\leq t_{f}\right\} ,
$$
with $\tau>0$ a scalar constant, and $u_{1}(t)$ and $u_{2}(t)$ are elements of $\mathbf{u}(t)$. It is this final path constraint which troubles me.

Comment: Your formulation for the path constraint might have some ambiguity. For example when $t_0<0$ and $t_f>0$ then if $t<0$ then $t_0\leq\tau\,t<0$, if $t=0$ then $\tau\,t=0$ and if $t>0$ then $0>\tau\,t\leq t_f$. I am not sure if this is intended behavior, otherwise you could formulate it as: $$u_1(t) - u_2(\tau)=0\ \forall\,t,\tau\in\{x:t_0\leq x\leq t_f\}$$

Comment: Or is $\tau$ a constant positive parameter?

Comment: Yes, edited to clarify.